# KL divergence between 2 distributions with unequal cardinalities?

Tags: probability, information-theory, mutual-information, kullback-leibler

Say $X$ is a discrete random variable with cardinality $|X|$ and $Y$ is a discrete random variable with cardinality $|Y|$.

Does it make sense to talk about the KL divergences $D_{KL}(X||Y)$ or $D_{KL}(Y||X)$ of these 2 probability distributions if $|X| \neq |Y|$ ? If so, how does one compute it ?

Comment: From the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Definition): "The K-L divergence is only defined if $P$ and $Q$ both sum to $1$ and if $Q(i)=0$ implies $P(i)=0$ for all $i$ (absolute continuity)." Therefore the answer in general is: no.

Comment: [A related question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6907/an-adaptation-of-the-kullback-leibler-distance). Didier's answer there, in particular, is highly relevant.

Comment: An example: If $X$ has the possible values $0,1,2$ and $Y$ has the possible values $0,1,2,3$ and your observation is $3$, then $X$ is excluded as a model by usual, determinisic logic! Sothe power to discriminate between these twomodels is infinitely large, and you could , if you want, define KL-divergence from $X$ to$Y$ to be $\infty$, if that makes sense. The KL-divergence in the other direction could be finite.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense to think of $D_{KL}(Y||X) = \inf$ and compute $D_{KL}(X||Y)$ for values $0,1,2$ in your example.